# Calculadora Simples - Como usar o comando 'elif' para definir condição em python?

Tags: python, condição

Tenho um exercício para fazer que é para fazer uma Calculadora Simples, em python. Primeiro fiz o pseudocódigo e depois passei para python, com o seguinte código:

```
print("Bem Vindo à Calculadora Simples!")

num1 = float(input("Insira um número: "))

num2 = float(input("Insira um número: ")) 

operacao = input("Escolha uma oparação (+, -, /, *): ")

if operacao == "+":
    resultado = num1 + num2
print("O resultado é: ", resultado)

elif operacao == "-":
    resultado = num1 - num2
print("O resultado é: ", resultado)

elif operacao == "/":
    resultado = num1 / num2
print("O resultado é: ", resultado)

elif operacao == "*":
    resultado = num1 * num2
print("O resultado é: ", resultado)

else:
    print("Operação inválida, selecione apenas +, -, / ou *")
```

Quando executo essa parte das condições aparece esse erro:

```
elif operacao == "/":
^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Não sei qual é o erro de sintaxe, o que devo fazer?

Comment: Em Python a indentação é importante. Repare que o `print` não está alinhado com a linha anterior, portanto ele está fora do `if`, encerrando-o. Então o `elif` fica "solto", sem um `if` correspondente. Corrigindo a indentação, deve funcionar

Comment: realmente foi isso, coloquei a identação correta e foi, um erro tão bobo, obrigada pela ajuda

Answer (score -2, accepted):

O elif em python só funciona em conjunto com o comando if. Quando você dá o print recuando a identação, o programa sai  do escopo do if. E, na hora de você usar o elif, a máquina do python não encontra o if para associar ao elif. A única  coisa que você precisa fazer é inserir os prints dentro de seu respectivo if ou elif, deste jeito abaixo:

```
print("Bem Vindo à Calculadora Simples!")

num1 = float(input("Insira um número: "))

num2 = float(input("Insira um número: ")) 

operacao = input("Escolha uma oparação (+, -, /, *): ")

if operacao == "+":
    resultado = num1 + num2
    print("O resultado é: ", resultado)

elif operacao == "-":
    resultado = num1 - num2
    print("O resultado é: ", resultado)
...
```

Espero ter sido claro e boa sorte nos seus estudos.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: foi exatamente esse o erro, muito obrigada!

Answer (score -3):

Deu SyntaxError por que você não criou uma variável para "resultado". Se criar a variável "resultado" teria que criar uma para cada operador.
EXEMPLO:
IF operacao == "+":
print(resultado1)
elif operacao == "-":
Print(resultado2)
Etc...

O mais fácil seria

IF operacao == "+":
Print(num1 + num2)

E assim por diante

Comment: Isso não faz o menor sentido.

Answer (score -8):

Substitua a função "operação" pela função "print"

Comment: Isso não faz o menor sentido.